# Is it possible to change the ID of a BTRFS subvolume?

Tags: linux, filesystems, arch-linux, btrfs

I want to make the IDs of my subvolumes consecutive so I can access them easier. Is there any way to change the ID of a BTRFS subvolume without nuking the data it contains? If so, how would you do this? (I’m using Arch Linux by the way)

Comment: [Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/355310)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I just updated with some info

Comment: Can't you just access them by path instead? Every subvolume should have a `subvolid` and a `subvol`, and you only need to use one of those to mount the subvolume.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using LVM? How did you mount btrfs FS?

If you using LVM, you need to unmount FS and run lvrename.

Comment: I am not using LVM